# Why word "also" is counted as bad word in LateX?

Tags: texstudio

I am new to LateX.I am using TexStudio to prepare a homework report.While I was typing I see there are some warnings labelled "bad word". I just wondered how LateX is deciding which word is bad which are not?

It labels "also" as bad word.Why also is bad word,Why shouldn't I use it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't know why TeXStudio marks the word *also* as bad. It's not a LaTeX question, anyway, but of the grammar/spelling checker used by TeXStudio.

Comment: Thank you.I didn't even know it is not latex's property.But any way I learnt.

Comment: Are you using "also" repeatedly? If you use the same word repeatedly TeXstudio might flag it for word repetition.

Comment: "The greater $\sigma$ value causes more clear regions in resulting image but also causes some fine details to disappear"  This sentence is the only where I have used "also"

Comment: Please try "The greater $\sigma$ value causes clearer regions in the resulting image but also causes some fine details to disappear.", unless you mean that it causes the number of clear regions to increase, rather than causing some or all regions to become clearer.

Comment: In English, try to create main clauses that aren't overly long. I would suggest writing, "Setting a greater value for $\sigma$ results in clearer regions in the image. However, doing so also causes some fine details to disappear."